# Conformal mapping with positive derivative.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let G be a simply connected domain which is not whole plane,

and Let $p$ $\in$G.
show that if $f$ is a conformal map of G onto D(unit disk), such that $f(p)=0$ and $f'(p)>0$.

Then show that such a map $f$ is unique.

I don't know how to use positive derivative condition.

I'm working on using Power series, But Seems not proper.. I Gues..

Comment: Let $f_1,f_2$ be two such maps. Consider $f_2 \circ f_1^{-1} \colon D \to D$.

Comment: Is that reimann mapping theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks. I can prove that such composition is only linear, But How can I verify that this is identity map?

Comment: @Maryam Riemann Mapping Thm ensures that such a map's existence.

Comment: @nicksohn It's an automorphism of the unit disk that fixes $0$. The Schwarz lemma finishes it.

Comment: Ah! Ok I found it. it is just rotation, and f'(z)>0 condition implies that the constant of first degree term is 1.